# Problems trying to run Powershell code in command line (Load assembly)

Tags: powershell

I made some code that uses the New-Object command from the command line Powershell, but this error popped up whenever I tried to load anything from System.Windows:

```
PS C:\Users\USER> New-Object System.Windows.FontWeight
New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Windows.FontWeight]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Object System.Windows.FontWeight
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

This code works fine in Powershell ISE:

```
PS C:\Users\USER> New-Object System.Windows.FontWeight
Normal
```

If anyone can tell me what the problem is and how to fix it, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the assembly `PresentationCore` that contains type `System.Windows.FontWeight` is not loaded in your PowerShell session. Seems like PowerShell ISE and PowerShell Console do not preload the same assemblies. You can load the corresponding assembly as follows:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell ISE loads the containing assembly on startup to build its own GUI.

In `powershell.exe` you'll have to load it yourself:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore |Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FontWeight Structure` is present in the `System.Windows` namespace and `PresentationCore` assembly. As evident from the error, you need to add the assembly `PresentationCore` to your PowerShell command line. Use this and you will be good to go.

```
Add-Type -Assembly PresentationCore
```